# spring security jar files are not being downloaded by maven

Tags: maven, jar, spring-security

The spring security jar files are missing from my project classpath.
Maven clean and install execute successfully but doesn't download jar files for spring-security which I have mentioned in my pom.xml(see below).All other jar files are being downloaded successfully.

below is the dependencies for for my project - POM.xml

```
<version.org.springframework>3.2.4.RELEASE</version.org.springframework>
<version.org.springframework.security>3.2.4.RELEASE</version.org.springframework.security>

<!-- Spring framework dependency management -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework.security}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework.security}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework.security}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework.security}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework.security}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring MVC -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.springframework}</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Delete your USER_HOME/.m2/repository/org/ directory and do a clean install.

Comment: I delete and tried it again, this time no folder or jar created for spring-security. All other jars  are there except these spring-security jars.

Comment: I think last time spring-security jars were created because of my testing with some other pom.xml.......... In my project the actual problem is that, these jars are not being downloaded by maven...............see the updated question. - @shazin

Comment: please run `mvn clean install -X` and edit your post with the `ERROR` lines

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not resolved. Did you initialize it properly?

As you can see here

http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:pom:${spring.version} from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at index 86: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/${spring.version}/spring-security-web-${spring.version}.pom

Initialize `$spring-version`

Comment: I haven't useed this variable anywhere in my pom.xml, whit what value should i initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete those files, which contains **`${spring.version}`**, and fix your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <version.org.springframework>3.2.4.RELEASE</version.org.springframework>
    <version.org.springframework.security>3.2.4.RELEASE</version.org.springframework.security>
</properties>
```

Also wrap your `<dependency>` tags with a `<dependencies>` tag.
If it's a root pom, you should use a `<dependencyManagement>` tag.

Comment: I have shared only partial POM.xml file, these values are placed properly in properties tag and dependencies tag respectively.